# is_home() and is_single() Not Working as Expected with Custom Post Types?

Tags: customization, custom-post-types, sidebar

(**Moderators note:** Was originally titled: *"Custom post type problem?"*)

I'm having some problems with custom post types where everything is working great except for the sidebars.

Here is some code from my `sidebar.php`:

```
<?php
  if (is_home()) {
    dynamic_sidebar('frontpage-sidebar');
  }
  if (is_single()) {
    dynamic_sidebar('single-post-sidebar');
  }
  ....
?>
```

Normally this works ok except for when I open a single page to check post `'frontpage-sidebar'` is not loading as the `'single-post-sidebar'` is loading instead. Where is the problem?

Here is the code for my custom post type:

```
$labels = array(
  'name' => _x('Tools', 'post type general name'),
  'singular_name' => _x('Tool', 'post type singular name'),
  'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Tool'),
  'add_new_item' => __('Add New Tool'),
  'edit_item' => __('Edit Tool'),
  'new_item' => __('New Tool'),
  'view_item' => __('View Tool'),
  'search_items' => __('Search Tools'),
  'not_found' => __('No Tools found'),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Tools found in Trash'),
  'parent_item_colon' => ''
);
$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => 2,
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','page-attributes') // 'not sure that post can have page-attributes ????'
);
register_post_type('tools', $args);
```

How do I load different sidebars on different pages when using custom post types instead of  ordinary posts?

Thanks.

Comment: I try also this tut http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress but same result my homepage sidebar is loaded on single page also,...

Comment: It just won't load sidebar in single.php,when printing ordinary post,it loads sidebar,but for custom types,it won't load sidebar

Comment: *@user1147* I edited your question heavily to try to make it more clear *(please review to make sure I didn't change the meaning.)* One thing I didn't understand was when you said *"when I open a single page to check post"*; can you be more clear what you meant by *"single page?"*

Comment: Sorry,when open single post,to check it,sidebar for single post is not loaded,I don't have pages,just categories.

Comment: *@user1147* - See my update below.

Comment: I think conditions is_home and is_single must insert before function wp_footer()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then use are asking why `is_home()` is `false` when you are viewing the URL `/tools/example-tool/`?  If I understand your question the answer is simply that is_home() is not `true` for Custom Post Types.

Actually `is_home()` should never be `true` except for 1.) when on the home page list of posts, or 2.) when a *"static page"* has been set to be a *"Posts page"* in the *Settings > Reading* section of the admin *(In my screen shot my "Posts page" has been set to a "Page" -- `post_type=='page'` -- whose Title is "Home"):*

[image: Setting a Home Page in WordPress 3.0's Admin Console]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101014-021612.png))</sub>

So if you want the sidebar to show up I think you'll need to use a different criteria than `is_home()`. Can you describe in words what you were trying to accomplish this code?

### UPDATE

Based on the comments below and [**subsequent research**](http://bit.ly/is-home-fails-with-cpts) after better understanding the problem it appears **appropriate values for `is_home()` and `is_single()` were never really defined for custom post types**. So one of the better solutions to the problem is to create a post type specific theme template page, i.e. `single-tools.php` if the post type is `tools`, and define sidebars specifically for that post type. **But if you must route everything through one `single.php`** then here are some functions that you could use in place of `is_home()` and `is_single()` to achieve the expected results and you can store these in your theme's `functions.php` file *(or one of of the files of a plugin)*:

```
function is_only_home() {
  $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
  return is_home() && empty($post_type);
}

function is_any_single() {
  $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
  return is_single() || !empty($post_type);
}
```

Taking your first code example above and applying these function would look like this:

```
<?php
  if (is_only_home()) {
    dynamic_sidebar('frontpage-sidebar');
  }
  if (is_any_single()) {
    dynamic_sidebar('single-post-sidebar');
  }
  ....
?>
```

Comment: Yes,it helps,but did not solve the problem,I use latest post for front page(not static page),according to this http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags I will only need to change sidebar.php to this if (is_front_page()) {
    dynamic_sidebar('frontpage-sidebar');
  }
  if (is_single()) {
    dynamic_sidebar('single-post-sidebar');
  } but this do not work,still on single page,where post is printed,sidebar from home page is loaded.I need to load different sidebars on different pages-posts,on home page first,on single second sidebar,... Tnx Mike

Comment: single page = single post

Comment: *@user1147* - I've reread your comment several times and still can't understand what you are asking. Can you update your question with actual URLs, and screenshots if possible, and showing what content you want to show up where?

Comment: Sorry,thanks for your patience,it is on my localhost,I will try again to explain.I have register several sidebars:front-page-sidebar,single-post-sidebar,...,when I put calendar widget on front page sidebar it is working fine(calendar widget is loaded on fronpage),but when I put category widget on single post sidebar it is showing me again calendar widget(calendar widget is again loaded in single post,even I put category widget in this sidebar).When using standard post type,it is working fine,but when I use custom post type,it doesn't work.

Comment: *@user1147* - Are you using a one `single.php` template for all post types?  Have you considered creating a `single-tools.php` for other your `tools` custom post type instead?  I know it does not answer your *"Why?"* question, but it may get you what you want?

Comment: *@user1147* - So it seems that you've run across an undefined condition where `is_home()` can't be depended on for custom post types *(see: http://bit.ly/is-home-fails-with-cpts)* so I'm going to write an update at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.I use single.php for just one post type,and I have create single-page.php(page template) for standard post type,standard post type will be printed on pages.Didn't know how to use standard post types and custom post types together on posts,is your suggestion with single-tools.php solution for that,any tutorial,link for your example with single-tools.php?I'm still learning custom post types.Sorry on my bad English.Tnx.

Comment: *@user1147* - No problem your English is much better than my non-English. :) This should help: http://bit.ly/wp-templates-for-cpts

Comment: hahaha :))))) tnx for link and help Mike.

Answer (score 5):

The function you want to use:
[`is_singular($post_types)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) where `$post_types` is string/array of custom post types. The function returns true if a singular page is being displayed.

Comment: This is the correct-est answer.

Comment: This function desperately needs an extra parameter for including a `$post_id`.